# ignore a specific row when sorting in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, sort

So, I'm displaying some information on a lightning-datatable. The last two columns, show two different kind of prices, so for each page in the datatable, I add a last row at the end to show to total of all the prices in each row, like this:

[image]

At first I was satisfied, but then I realized, that when sorting those two columns, the total row also reacts to this, so it doesn't work for me. This is the sortData method in my lwc:

```
sortData(fieldName, direction){
    let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

    let keyValue = (a) => {
        return a[fieldName];
    };

    let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;

    parseData.sort((x, y) => {
        x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : '';
        y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
        return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
    });

    this.data = parseData;
}
```

Is there a way to ignore this row to be sorted and make it stay at the bottom? Or should I make another approach, like showing the total separately from the datatable and make it rerender when the page changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a separate copy of the data, sans the total row, and then tack it on at the end.

```
sortData(fieldName, direction){
  let parseData = [...this.dataFromServer];
  let keyValue = (a) => {
    return a[fieldName];
  };
  let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
  parseData.sort((x, y) => {
    x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : '';
    y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
    return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
  });
  this.data = [...parseData, this.calculateTotal()];
```

Where calculateTotal returns the data for the calculation, and dataFromServer is the original, unsorted and unmodified data from the server call that obtained the data to begin with.

Comment: perfect solution. thank you very much!